# How to remove or uninstall Resharper Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Even if the title should speak for itself, the question is, how to remove an already installed Plugin for Resharper.

In my case, i'm using Resharper 2017.2.1.

I wanted to test the *Agent Smith* - Plugin. After a short amount of time i was driven crazy about all the pseudo-errors in my Error-window. As you can imagine my first intention was using the Plugin-Manager (the Resharper one) to uninstall said plugin. But obviously, there is no such option.

Even hours of google brought me to no Solution.

Was anyone able to reproduce and fix my Issue? All ideas welcome

**Edit**

[image: Resharper]

My Extensionmanager

**Edit 2**
Proof, that Agent Smith Plugin is still installed

[image: Resharper Plugin]

Comment: Whats at the top of the list? Are there any installed plugins listed there?

Comment: @Lennart Bigger Screenshot now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with an Version-Update of Resharper.

After doing this, no plugin is showing any longer.
Probably reinstalling Resharper might also could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to uninstall all Resharper Extensions via its Extension Manager:

[image]